# CWSAD0016W - IBM WAS Node require the Feature Pack for Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

How do i replicate the below issue  on WAS 6.1.0.21?
`CWSAD0016W - Node require the Feature Pack for Web Services`

It's popping up on 6.1.0.45 on some upper end environments of clients. Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Do i have to disable any feature on default installation of WAS 6.1.0.21 or 6.1.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install deploy a JAX-WS application to a node that doesn't have the web services feature pack.  You shouldn't bother doing this on any maintenance level that didn't support the feature pack, because it won't know/care that your app is jax-ws.

6.1.0.11 looks like where the feature pack "enablement" was likely added: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27011716#61011